# Changing a global variable during a build and use it in a downstream build

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to create a global variable in jenkins which can be modified during builds, and is accessible to all projects in both master and slave machines?

I've tried modifying a global variable in a build, and see if this changed value is preserved in the downstream build.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But the value of `ttt` in `TestDownStreamParameter` is still `ttt_default`. It is not changed by the upstream build.

Anyone know how to achieve the goal I want?

Is there any plugin which can do the same thing?

I've also tried saving the value of `ttt` into a file. But this is inconvenient, because I have to transfer the file to the slave machines in order to use `ttt` on those machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define *Environment Variables* in the Jenkins global configuration. Those will be available to all jobs.

You could **modify the value of those global variables** with a Groovy script that you run as part of your job.

Comment: Can you provide an example of modifying the value of global variables using groovy? This makes the answer easier to understand by everyone :)

Comment: If you're looking for the actual _implementation_ of solving your problem using my suggested solution: [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/KgCGuDmED1Q/hL2kZEIMsr0J) has an example for modifying the global environment variables via Groovy.